# Center of Sums method - centroid of different shapes question

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, data-analysis

I'm doing fuzzy logic and I need to use the center of sums method to calculate a value.

I have the graph of functions here:

[image]

Sorry for the low quality, but I think this suffices.

The formula is with regards to the center of sums is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n A_1x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n A_1}$

Where $A_i$ are the areas and $x_i$ are the **x coordinates of the centroids/geometric centers of the areas**.

Now, let's just observe the trapezoid to the left (i.e. the one where $x \in (0, 0.5)$. I'm having trouble determining the geometric centre for the trapezoid to the left. I know that for a symmetric figure (i.e. a rectangle), the geometric center would be in the middle of its x span. However, since my trapezoid isn't symmetric, I have trouble finding it.

Could someone help?

Comment: Divide a Trapezoid into two triangles (you could do it in two ways). The center is on the line connecting the two triangles' centers and since you may get two segments where the intersection of them is the center of the trapezoid. The center of the two trapezoids define the line on which the center of both is - thus the center for the two is based on the ratio of the "weights".